# cloud firestore database creation

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

when i am create a new cloud firestore in my firebase project when moving in the first step they put for me the database id 'default' it is not editable ,and when continuing the next step and starting in the test mode and tab create they put for me this message :

> Error creating Firestore database Database already exists. Please use another database_id

i tried different ways of creating it but same error.

btw: i have on my pc 4+ databases(xamp,wamp,workbench,oracle plus) i use them for uni.
so may the problem be from them?

Comment: If you're having a problem with the Firebase console not working the way you expect, you should file an issue with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Creating multiple Firestore databases in a project is only possible when your project is on the paid plan and has an associated billing account. Is your project on the paid plan?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @Frank van Puffelen commented, check out the [Free quota](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#free-quota) of  Cloud Firestore. You usually start with the **default** database. the usage of named (non-default) databases is not included in the free usage.

Alternatively, if you have billing enabled, you can try to [create Firestore database](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/databases/create) with Firestore API:

```
gcloud firestore databases create --location=location --database=databaseId
```